# Can I build libc++ to be independent from MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++, clang, libc++

I know that libc++ support for Windows is experimental but it still can be built, right? I installed latest MSVC Build Tools, installed official clang binaries and successfully built the library.
When I ask clang to use libc++ headers it still keeps searching for `urct` headers or some internal MSVC headers:

```
....... C:/Program Files (x86)/libcxx/include/c++/v1\\errno.h
........ C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.18362.0\\ucrt\\errno.h
```

or

```
.... C:/Program Files (x86)/libcxx/include/c++/v1\\new
..... C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.18362.0\\ucrt\\new.h
...... C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\include\\vcruntime_new_debug.h
....... C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\include\\vcruntime_new.h
...... C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\include\\crtdefs.h
```

It compiles successfully but fails to link with undefined references to almost everything (tries to link `libc++.lib`). But if I don't specify headers it uses MSVC headers and builds successfully with `-defaultlib=libcmt`. Can I build it to work independently of MSVC or at least what am I doing wrong with using libc++ headers?

Comment: Standard C++ library have to use some C library. If not ucrt, what C library are you going to use?

Comment: @arrowd I'm ready to stick to headers only but then at least I need it to work - it doesn't